# React/React Hooks: Unknown prop type error on input, can't figure out how to resolve

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-hooks, react-proptypes

I have a component that I've set up using react hooks and I've passed a unique prop type to an input to handle the styling changes when there's an error with the user input. Everything works as expected but now I'm getting an unknown props error in the console and I can't figure out how to resolve it. 
The error

```
React does not recognize the `isError` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `iserror` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
```

The Component

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Col, Row, Input, Checkbox } from "antd";

function validateEmail(value) {
  const errors = {};
  if (value === "") {
    errors.email = "Email address is required";
  } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(value)) {
    errors.email = "Email address is invalid";
  }
  return errors;
}

const CustomerDetails = ({ customer }) => {
  const { contact = {} } = customer || {};
  const [disableInput, setDisableInput] = React.useState(false);
  const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState({});
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState(contact.email);

  function onBlur(e) {
    setErrors(validateEmail(e.target.value));
  }

  function clearInput() {
    setInputValue(" ");
  }

  function handleInputChange(event) {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  }

  function CheckboxClick() {
    if (!disableInput) {
      clearInput();
    }
    setDisableInput(prevValue => !prevValue);
    setErrors({})
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col span={8}>
          <StyledInput
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            disabled={disableInput}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            isError={!!errors.email}
          />
          {errors.email && <ErrorDiv>{errors.email}</ErrorDiv>}
        </Col>
        <Col span={8}>
          <Checkbox value={disableInput} onChange={CheckboxClick} /> EMAIL OPT
          OUT
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

const Container = styled.div`
  text-align: left;
`;

const StyledInput = styled(Input)`
  max-width: 100%;
  background: white;

  &&& {
    border: 2px solid ${props => props.isError ? '#d11314' : 'black'};
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 35px;
  }
`;

const ErrorDiv = styled.div`
  color: #d11314;
`;

export default CustomerDetails;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because `styled-components` passes through all props for custom react-components. See the documentation here: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props

You can avoid the error by following the pattern described here: https://www.darrenlester.com/blog/prevent-all-props-being-passed

In your case this would look something like:

```
   const ErrorInput = ({ isError, ...remaining }) => <Input {...remaining} />;
   const StyledInput = styled(ErrorInput)`
      max-width: 100%;
      background: white;

      &&& {
        border: 2px solid ${props => (props.isError ? "#d11314" : "black")};
        border-radius: 0px;
        height: 35px;
      }
    `;
```

Full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-wright-2l32l

To support React PropTypes:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const ErrorInput = ({ isError, ...remaining }) => <Input {...remaining} />;
ErrorInput.propTypes = {
  isError: PropTypes.bool
}
```

Comment: This got rid of the error but now I'm picking up a warning from my eslint saying ```Line 296:  'isError' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types``` any ideas on how to clear this too? Thanks also for the solution this was great

Comment: You should declare the prop type of isError to be a boolean. This is the documentation for React PropTypes. https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html. You want something like:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
ErrorInput.propTypes = {
  isError: PropTypes.bool
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this happens is:

The `Input` component from `antd` returns `input` html tag (`<input ... />`).

When you pass `Input` to `styled`, it also returns the `input` with the styles added.

```
const StyledInput = styled(Input)`...`  // this will return <input ... />
```

`styled(Input)` isn't like a wrapper with some element around. It just get the component, and add the styles.

`styled(SomeComponent)` use your props to style `SomeComponent` but also pass props down to `SomeComponent`. This will pass `isError` to `input` tag (`<input isError={...}` />)  and when you do this, react will try to find a input property `isError` wich doesn't exists, giving you the error.

I hope this explanation helps you understand better why this happens, but so far, what you can do is lowercase your prop name.

## Edit:

As the other answers says and looking at [this article](https://www.darrenlester.com/blog/prevent-all-props-being-passed), you can avoid `isError` to be passed to the `input` by creating a wrapper component that removes `isError` prop.

```
const WrappedInput = ({ isError, ...remaining }) => <Input {...remaining} />;

const StyledInput = styled(WrappedInput)`...`
```

Comment: It does, but when I changed everything to lower case I'm getting the following error ```index.js:1446 Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `iserror`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: iserror="false" or iserror={value.toString()}.```

Comment: @JCalkins89 you can check my edit and also the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `Input` component will blindly forward all attributes it receives and can't recognise to the underlying DOM element. `styled` will also forward all props to the underlying element. The ideal solution is to check whether `styled` will allow you a syntax that "absorbs" props instead of forwarding them. There's [an FAQ entry](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#why-am-i-getting-html-attribute-warnings) on this in the `styled` documentation:

Unfortunately the solution only works if you are styling your own components. As a workaround you can create a proxy Input you can then style:

```js
const ProxyInput = ({ isError, ...props }) => <Input {...props} />

const StyledInput = styled(ProxyInput)`
  max-width: 100%;
  background: white;

  &&& {
    border: 2px solid ${props => props.isError ? '#d11314' : 'black'};
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 35px;
  }
`;
```

This is not ideal and you may opt to just make the properly lowercased `iserror` as others suggest. I only mention this alternative in case you don't like random attributes bleeding into your DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/2527) with react-fontawesome. The styled-components staff say this is most likely an issue that the maintainers of the library in which the problem is happening (antd) will need to solve. For now, I simply lowercased my DOM prop, which will cause the error to not get shown.